# sidebar menu stopped functioning

Tags: blocks

I've inherited a website that I need to fix.  Currently I'm working on a sidebar menu functionality has stopped working for no apparent reason.  We have an old copy of the website where the sidebar menu is working.  I've compared the Main Menu Links and configuration of Blocks>sidebar first.  Everything appears to be the same.  I've run windiff at the sites/all/themes level and any differences are either comments or recent font changes I've made. One thing I've noticed is a change to the title of a php file under /sites/all/themes/ccom/templates/block--menu_block--3.tpl.php to ...5.tpl.php.  I've changed any references to the 3 to the 5 in the style.css and that style part starts functioning, sort of, but I can't get it to function how it does in the old version.  I've even reverted the menu_block module (ver 7.x-2.7) back to the original version (ver 7.x-2.4). Didn't fix anything.  I haven't done that to the block module (current 7.43 old 7.31).  Block_Class is the same in both (7.x-1.3).

**Old Version**
https://webtest.ccom.nh/theme/law-sea
 (Click on any sidebar item and a sidebar will appear above the sidebar-first area with additional menu items.  Sometimes there are no submenus, but at least the main menu item will show bolded.)

**Current Version**
https://webdev.ccom.nh/theme/law-sea
 (Click on any sidebar item and nothing shows above the sidebar-first menu.  Click on Law of the Sea, then click on a coordinate on the image of the earth and the desired menu appears. It is also showing orange arrows to indicate active and nothing on hover.)

I am at a loss as to why it is not working and where to look.  Thanks for helping me figure this out in advance.

Comment: your links are not working for me

Comment: Ah, right, permissions.  This is the production site, in which this sidebar menu is incorrectly working.  http://ccom.unh.edu/theme/law-sea

Comment: so what are the rules of this 'orange menu block', where do you show it ?? by contenttype, or what ?